# How to use update-alternatives in an alternate root path

Tags: alternatives

Is there a way to have the `update-alternatives` command operate on a root file system mounted on a path other than '/'?  For example, the `update-rc.d` and `ldconfig` commands have an `-r <path>` option to do this. The `update-alternatives` man page does not indicate such support.

Comment: Can you chroot in into the root file system, and run the command in that chroot?

Comment: Thanks.  I had resolved this issue with some shell scripting to do the equivalent of the update-alternatives command.  The chroot option looks like it will also work and would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--admindir` option to choose a state directory such as `/my/root/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`, and the `--altdir` option to choose a link directory such as `/my/root/etc/alternatives`. However `update-alternatives` will see absolute symbolic links in `/my/root/etc/alternatives`, pointing to `/usr/bin` and the like, so it might see broken links for programs that aren't installed in the alternate root.

There's no option to tell it to work entirely inside a root. So use the generic method: [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

```
chroot /my/root update-alternatives …
```

If you don't want to run as root, you can use [fakechroot](https://github.com/dex4er/fakechroot).